# Can comment editing time be extended?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, comments

Often I want to correct either a typo or an inaccurate statement I've made in a comment. But, after 5 minutes I can't.

I realize I can delete the comment and simply make a new comment, but wouldn't it be better if there wasn't a 5 minute limit on comment editing?

Comment: Could also be dependent on rep, if you have more than x rep then you can edit your own comments as much as you like.

Comment: Found this on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34046/proposal-to-streamline-comment-editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [status-declined](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing), which means it won't be implemented here. If there arguments for or against this feature that you don't think are represented on that meta question, feel free to weigh in!

Comment: If the answer by Dennis on meta did little to persuade, I doubt I could do better. Thanks.